# Why running sudo to my own account fixes graphical problems in Swing GUI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, look-and-feel, sudo

My swing GUI application starts with a script.

When I run that script under Linux without sudo it gives me unexpected  Look and feel and other graphical problems.

Why is running with sudo su to my own account fixes this problem?

Comment: To be clear, you are invoking `su` via `sudo` to change to your own uid, and it magically works?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. 
I am invoking script using sudo. I also can invoke it as 
sudo su myname myScriptName. Question is about sudo. Gui looks great when I ran script whith sudo, and not so if without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

One might guess that the program is trying to make use of a file that has permissions that allow root to access it, but not your uid.  Perhaps you have a library installed with wrong permissions?

`strace` will tell you what files your app is trying to access.